# How to make a program shut itself down

Tags: c

How do I make a program shut itself down after user says y in case 3. I want when they press y in case 3 that program exits it self like it would when compiling is done. I'm trying to make a menu where you can browse trough the options its not complete yet I need to make play, graphics, sounds case. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
     int op1;

     printf("1.Play\n");
     printf("2.Options\n");
     printf("3.Exit\n");


     scanf(" %d", &op1);

     char ans;

     switch(op1)
     {
           case 1 : printf("Press 5 to start a new game");
                 break;
           case 2 : printf("1.Graphics\n"); printf("2.Sound\n");
                 break;
           case 3 :  printf("Are you sure (y/n)");
                 scanf(" %c", &ans);
                 if(ans =='y')
                 {

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     printf("1.Play\n");
                     printf("2.Options\n");
                     printf("3.Exit\n"); 
                 }
            default : printf("Wrong choice.");
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use exit(0);

Comment: In order to exit gracefully. Just use the exit() system call.

Comment: For some reason the exit(0); is not working when i put in the if statement when ans == 'y' and when i press y the console just stays there and waits for me to hit any key.Any help on that?

Comment: Try `_exit(0)`. Note the underscore. Even otherwise, since you are doing this inside `main()`, what's the problem with just issuing a `return 0;`?

Comment: @IgorPavkovic stdin is generally line buffered. It sounds like you're looking for an equivalent of a keyboard-hit (i.e. detect a keystroke; not just a character-input on stdin) you're going to have to go to a library like conio (advice: just don't) or [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses). All of this, assuming you fix the compile-time error(s) in your posted code and implant the `return 0;` or `exit(0)` solutions mentioned.

Comment: @WhozCraig why not conio.h (im still learning C not a total pro so i just need some people to tell me what to avoid :D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is to be restricted to the `main()` method, then just return out.

```
 if(ans == 'y') {
     return 0;
 }
```

It is a good practice to avoid hard exits unless you really need them.

But if you really need to hard exit out, you may try `_exit(0);` here. `exit(0);` as well, which has already been mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `y` is not a variable, you have to compare with the character code:

```
if (ans == 'y') {...}
```

To terminate your program, use:

```
exit(0);
```